# volume of a set using principle of Cavalieri

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to calculate $\lambda_2(A)$ for $A:=\{(xy^2,y^{-1})^T:x,y\in(0,2)\}$. ($\lambda_2$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$).
I thought about using the principle of Cavalieri. So I have to calculate $\int_\mathbb R\lambda_1(M_y)d\lambda_1(y)$ for $M_y:=\{x\in \mathbb R:(x,y)\in A\}$. But how can I calculate $\lambda_1(M_y)$?

Comment: What is $M$? You did not define it.

Comment: I mean $A$. I corrected it.